# how to setup ide for a chroot'ed project

Tags: c, cmake, ide, clion, chroot

I am trying to build i3wm (https://github.com/i3/i3), inside my basic debian `/chroot/stretch`. I am using an IDE installed in my host, not in chroot. However, I realized it's complicated, because all `include` directives are resolved on host, instead of being resolved in `/chroot/stretch` ...

My question is:

- How do I use an IDE (in my case, CLion) from host to build, and develop projects inside a `chroot`ed environment?
- Should I use a full blown VM, with X forwarding, instead of chroot?
- any other tool?... May be I can download all dependencies on the host, without chroot, and somehow trick `include` into taking those headers, instead of ones in `/usr/include` ?

I am really new to C, and the fact that my development setup might mess with my system is a quite annoying, and I am surprised and couldn't find something like "setup-your-tools-for-development" instructions on google..

**EDIT:** so 2 years later myself here: forget vim and chroot, I use docker + VScode which works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

Okey, I guess using VIM + Ctags is the only solution, no need for a VM...